# Conditional statements in association model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 2.3.8. I have the following in my view:

```
<% if !@shop.city_shops.blank? %>
  <% @shop.city_shops.each do |city_shop|  %>
    <% if !city_shop.notes.blank? %>
      <% city_shop.notes %>
    <% else %>
      <p>No notes.</p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
 <p>No notes.</p>
<% end %>
```

`city_shops` has a database column called `notes`; `belongs_to` `shop`.
`shop` `has_many` `city_shops`.

In article `A`, I add a `shop with ID 50` into a new row `city_shop`, and add `notes`.
In article `B`, I add a `shop with ID 50` into a new row `city_shop`, and no notes.
In article `C`, I add a `shop with ID 51` into a new row `city_shop`, and no notes.

Result of `city_shop` database:

```
ID | shop_id | notes
1  |   50    | Test
2  |   50    | 
3  |   51    |
```

In `view.html.erb` of `shop 50`, I want to show the notes `Test` from `city_shop` ID 1.

In `view.html.erb` of `shop 51`, I want to show the `No notes` from `city_shop` ID 3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% no_notes = false %>   

<% @shop.city_shops.each do |city_shop|  %>
 <% unless city_shop.notes.blank? %>
   <% city_shop.notes %>
 <% else %>
   <% no_notes = true %>
 <% end %> 
<% end %>

<% if no_notes %>
  <p>No notes.</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting the "wrong number of arguments" for line "<% if city_shop.notes.count > 0 %>"

Comment: is notes an active record assosiation?

Comment: Notes is a column in city_shops, and city_shops belongs_to :shops, shops has_many :city_shops

Comment: are you sure the error is in <% if city_shop.notes.count > 0 %>? Try to remove the next line (<% city_shop.notes %>) with <p>notes here!</p>

Comment: Yes, sure about that error. Doesn't work after replacing that line.

Comment: But notes is not a separate model. It's a column in CityShop.

Comment: change <% if city_shop.notes.count > 0 %> to <% unless city_shop.notes.blank? %>

Comment: Thanks. Now when city_shop.notes is not blank, the <p>No notes.</p> still appears.

Comment: do you use unless instead of if in <% unless city_shop.notes.blank? %>?

Comment: I replaced <% if city_shop.notes.count > 0 %> with <% unless city_shop.notes.blank? %>. Others left intact.

Comment: Hmm. Now, when city_shop.notes not blank, notes and <p>No notes</p> will both be shown; when city_shop.notes blank, none will be shown; when city_shop.notes not blank but notes is empty, <p>No notes</p> will be shown.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question because i'm not sure what you really ask for.

Comment: Hey Tarscher, I think I gotta stop working on this part as I have some other bugs that prevent this from working too even if this fix works. So sorry for the trouble, but I appreciate your time very much. Thanks again!